# Get integer from UIAlertview

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uialertview

I'm going to create count-down function

By

press ADDTIMEBUTTON > UIAlert to get number > press Start

I confused about how to get number

```
int number;

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    number = [[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text] intValue];
}

- (IBAction)AddTimeButton:(id)sender {

    //get number
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"GET TIME"
                                                    message:@"How many Seconds"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Enter", nil];

    [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    [alert show];
    [[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)buttonCountPressed:(id)sender {
   self.displaycount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number];
}
```

Sorry, about my english.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, The method you are currently using `didPresentAlertView:` is called even before you enter anything in the textfield. Use `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` delegate method to set number.

Second, you are using `int number` for getting number (which was never set) as you tried to set the number in a temporary variable `NSString *number`.

Do something like this to fix these issues:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    number = [[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text] intValue];
}
```

Comment: In delegate param of Alertview set **self** instead of **nil**

Answer (score 0):

you should set alert's delegate .

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
   initWithTitle:@"GER TIME" message:@"How many Seconds" 
   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:@"Enter", nil];
```

and implement UIAlertView Delegate

```
- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView{
     self.displaycount.text = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
}
```

Comment: I had done with your suggest it's work :) but my number didn't change

Comment: you forgot to set `delegate:self`.and did your Class implement UIAlertView Delegate??